# How to install libthrift-dev on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, thrift

'm trying to install thrift module "libthrift-dev" on my Ubuntu 14 as well as on Ubuntu 16. But, getting the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libthrift-dev
```

What is the best way to install "libthrift-dev" on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have a look at [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt).

Answer (score -1):

libthrift-dev is part of cassandra and scylla ppa, not part of the main distribution. you may want to add these ppa first.

Comment: how to add them?

Comment: Actually, the version of libthrift used in Scylla is not in any up-to-date PPA. For Ubuntu 19 and onward, it's part of the main repository:

For earlier version you could try libthrift 11 package from deepin distribution.

Comment: I see i am on ubuntu 18.04